# Type: ArgumentCountError

Tags: codeigniter

I want to save $id_lowongan,$id_kategori
but i get error

> Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Lowongan::lamar(), 1 passed in /home/denr6524/public_html/rekrutmen/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 2 expected

Filename: /home/denr6524/public_html/rekrutmen/application/controllers/pencari/Lowongan.php

Line Number: 45

Backtrace:

File: /home/denr6524/public_html/rekrutmen/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

this my controller

```
public function lamar($id_lowongan,$id_kategori) {
    $id_user        = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $profile        = $this->user_model->detail($id_user);
    $lowongan       = $this->lowongan_model->detail($id_lowongan);
    $kategori       = $this->kategori_model->detail($id_kategori);
    $lowongan = $this->lowongan_model->status_lamaran($id_user);


    $data = array( 
        'id_lowongan'    => $id_lowongan,
        'id_user'        => $id_user,
        'id_kategori'  =>  $id_kategori,
        'status_lamaran' => "Lamaran Sedang Diproses" 
    );
    $this->lowongan_model->lamaran($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Sukses', 'Lamaran Berhasil dikirim');


    redirect(base_url('pencari/lowongan'),'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too few arguments to function Lowongan::lamar()-> it seems you are passing $id_lowongan not $id_kategori, if you are passing $id_kategori(check value).Print these two values before calling the function!